# Most performing way to extract links to embedded resources in JSOUP

Tags: java, html, performance, parsing, jsoup

I have a question regarding the best way regarding the best way to parse a document to extract resource links.

You show in this cookbook:

- http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links

The following method which builds a DOM representation:

> ```
>     Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
>     Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
> ```

So I am not sure it's the most performing way.

- Is it better to iterate on doc.getAllElements() ?
- Or is there some kind of SAX parser equivalent ?

I asked this question on JSOUP googlegroups on 3 March, but I am not sure my mail has passed the filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most performing way would be to use the `NodeTraversor` which is an implementation of Visitor pattern. It will scan the whole tree just as two other options, but

- it won't require to parse the CSS query and match it 'dynamically' - it's less possible to JIT-optimize a custom query than a static filter
- it won't store the elements to a list as with `getAllElements()`

SAX parsing model is not supported because Jsoup always creates a DOM-tree, so there is no need in less-capable SAX. And so does `HtmlCleaner`.

```
final List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();

new NodeTraversor(new NodeVisitor() {
    public void head(Node node, int depth) {
        if (node instanceof Element) {
            Element element = (Element) node;
            if(element.tagName().equalsIgnoreCase("a") && element.hasAttr("href")){
                elements.add(element);
            }
        }
    }

    public void tail(Node node, int depth) {
    }
}).traverse(doc);

return elements;
```